# How to fix libCGAL-vc140-mt-4.14-l-900.lib Link error ( VCPKG CGAL update 4.14 )

Tags: c++, cgal, vcpkg

I'm getting the error message "Linker Tools Error LNK1104" can't find libCGAL-vc140-mt-4.14-I-900.lib"

I'm using VCPKG with Visual Studio and linker flag /MD or /MDd. (question 27970033) The same setup worked with CGAL 4.13. The error came after the update to 4.14 with VCPKG.

Even a small new CGAL program will not be translated. I tried debug/release mode with x64.

Comment: CGAL is now (4.14) installed as header only with vcpkg, so there shouldn't be any linker problem (and I don't have one on my system). Did you try with a clean build directory ? Did you try to remove/reinstall cgal ? It might be a cache effect of some sort that still expects a CGAL library but only gets the headers.